# How to add exexutable file to to toolbar

Tags: visual-studio-2010, toolbar

This may seem like a duplicate of some other questions posted. But i dint get appropriate replies out there.

I have one executable of name 'GenerateFileName.exe' which i want to embed to Visual Studio Toolbar.
I am using VS 2010.

Thanks in advance

Regardas,
Girish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [External Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9814d200.aspx) feature for this.

First, setup the External Tool - full instructions can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9814d200.aspx) but here are the quick steps:

1. Go to `Tools` menu and choose `External Tools`
2. Click `Add` and enter the details for your program (enter at least a title and then the path to the exe as the command)

Second, you need to add a toolbar icon for that External Tool.  Again, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdee4yb6.aspx) has the full details but the basics are:

1. Go to `Tools` menu and choose `Customize` and switch to the `Commands` tab
2. Select the option to rearrange the `Toolbar` and then select the toolbar you want to add to (e.g. "Standard")
3. Click `Add Command...`
4. Go to the `Tools` category and find External Tool XX.  Finding the item with the current number for XX might take some guess-and-check but you should be able to get it.